# How to reset infinispan statistics without restarting or stopping the application

Tags: java, wildfly, infinispan

I use infinispan in my wildfly 10 application deployed on three nodes. I can also view the statistics via a simple UI:

[image]

The statistics are called via: `cache.getAdvancedCache().getStats()`

No I have changed the `lifeSpan` time of a cached objects and need to reset the statistics (*timeSinceReset*) to see the new hit rate.

So is it possible to reset the statistics without stopping or restarting the nodes? Is there any *cli script* I can use or can I perhaps do reset programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Stats` object has a method `.reset()`, use that one.

Alternatively the statistics can be reset through JMX, look for object name `Statistics`, operation `resetStatistics`.